# Am I allowed to post a project URL on Stack Overflow so others can rate and review that project?

Tags: discussion, support, advertising, site-promotion, project

I am currently completing a PHP & jQuery related project and I'm interested if I can post a question on Stack Overflow so other programmers and developers from specified technologies could rate it, advise, review, test, suggest, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you complete the project, you can post your code for review at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Your code *must* be working, please read the [site's FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly before asking a question there.

Comment: I've read the FAQ' :) but I needed more clearifications on this, and your response helped the most! Thanks!

Comment: @Zlatan Hm? Just to clarify, I'm talking about Code Review's FAQ not Stack Overflow's.

Comment: well my project is a PHP lib. which fetches request jQuery versions to a local directory, or returns a "script" tag of jQuery CDN (google, microsoft, jquery), .. is this project OK to post on code review?

Comment: @Zlatan Yes, of course it is. Just make sure your code is working and that you include all of it in your question. If it's too much, just post the PHP lib and the jQuery scripts on separate questions. Browse the site a bit before posting, you'll quickly get the hang of it.

Comment: OK! But what if I have about 10 seperate classes, and few other plain php files? Should they be all in one question-post :/ ?

Comment: @Zlatan That might be a bit too much. You should ask a question on how to effectively break them into separate question on [Meta Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, nor some kind of social networking site. It's a Q&A site. Any attempt would likely be seen as a form of spam by the community. Rather post it in some discussion forum or a social networking site.

If you see on Stack Overflow a question which could be answered by using your library, then you can always post an elaborate answer how to solve it *without* the library and then in the end recommend in a neutral way your library as a possibly more easy solution. Do it only for active questions though and don't actively look for old questions and bump them up in a too short time with copypasted answers. That would also be seen as a form of spam.

Comment: You might want to add that one should *always* add a disclaimer when posting his/her work as answers, and also you should mention that this should *never* be the primary goal of being on the site. See [FAQ:Can I Promote Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for guidance.

Comment: Hmm, I understood that just mentioning it clearly in the user profile should be sufficient.